# Prove that $\phi_{h}(x) = \frac{1}{2h}\int_{x-h}^{x+h}f(t)dt \in L(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

> **Problem.** Given $f \in L(\mathbb{R})$, let
>   $$\phi_{h}(x) = \frac{1}{2h}\int_{x-h}^{x+h}f(t)dt,\quad h>0.$$
>   Prove that $\phi \in L(\mathbb{R})$ e $\displaystyle \int_{\mathbb{R}}|\phi_{h}(x)|dx \leq \Vert f \Vert_{1}.$

**My attempt.**

\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_{\mathbb{R}}|\phi_{h}(x)| & \leq & \frac{1}{2h}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{[x-h,x+h]}|f(t)|dtdx\\
& = & \frac{1}{2h}\underbrace{\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}|f(t)|\chi_{[x-h,x+h]}dtdx}_{\text{Fubini-Tonelli}}\\
& = & \frac{1}{2h}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}|f(t)|\chi_{[x-h,x+h]}dxdt\\
& = & \frac{1}{2h}\int_{\mathbb{R}}|f(t)|\underbrace{m([x-h,x+h])}_{m\text{ is the Lebesgue measure}}dt\\
& = & \int_{\mathbb{R}}|f(t)|dt\\
& = & \Vert f \Vert_{1}
\end{eqnarray*}

Is this correct?

Comment: no. first equality should be an inequality

Comment: But other than that,  it is correct.

Comment: Yes! Of course.. its a typo. Thank you

Comment: Should the fourth line be $m([t-h,t+h])$? Or would someone be kind enough to elaborate?

Comment: @Brofessor $\int\int|f(t)|\chi_{[x-h,x+h]}dxdt = \int|f(t)|(\int\chi_{[x-h,x+h]}dx)dt$. Since $\int\chi_{X}dx = \mathrm{vol}(X)$ the result follows.